# How can I have a Maven dependency on the runtime classpath but not the test classpath?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, dependencies

I have a case where I want a dependency on the runtime classpath but *not* the test classpath.  The dependency in question is Logback, an SLF4J implementation.  In runtime, I want my code to (optionally) depend on logback so that it has a logging infrastructure available.  At test time, however, I want to use the `slf4j-nop` implementation to black-hole the log output.  With `logback` as a runtime dependency and `slf4j-nop` as a test dependency, I get a multiple implementation warning from SLF4J when running my tests.  I do not see a way to exclude `logback` from the test classpath.

I do not want to split my tests into a separate package if it can be avoided.

Ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've finally found a real solution to this.  Since version 2.6 of the Maven Surefire plugin, there is now a [classpathDependencyExcludes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#classpathDependencyExcludes) configuration element that allows specific dependencies to be excluded from the classpath.  This therefore works:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8</version>
  <configuration>
    <classpathDependencyExcludes>
      <classpathDependencyExclude>ch.qos.logback:logback-classic</classpathDependencyExclude>
    </classpathDependencyExcludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved me a whole lot of time on research with this answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  Sad it seems like a hack... Wish we could get a "!" operator in the scope field.

Answer (score 2):

If disabling log output is what you want, add a logback configuration file to `src/test/resources` which discards all output.

If you need to do this for multiple modules in the same reactor build, consider using the [maven remote resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/).

> This plugin is used to retrieve JARs of resources from remote repositories, processes those resources, and incorporate them into JARs you build with Maven. A very common use-case is the need to package certain resources in a consistent way across your organization.

Comment: I might have to go with this; unfortunately, it would also require further project restructuring (it's a multi-module project, so I have to make sure that the config file is available in all of them).

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you don't have to exclude it from the test classpath. Maven should keep the order of dependencies in the classpath. If you put your test dependency before the runtime dependency in the dependencies it should also be first in the classpath and a ClassLoader should find the classes in the test dependency first when 2 dependencies contain the same classes. So slf4j would then find the static binding of slf4j-nop and not the logback binding.

Comment: Yes, however, SLF4J then prints a warning about multiple classpaths. I'm trying to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to add a dependency exclusion on logback from the slf4j-nop test-scoped dependency?  Something like

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>  
      <groupId>foo</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried this, but `exclude` only excludes transitive dependencies of the package in question; unfortunately, it seems it cannot be used to exclude arbitrary dependencies propagated in from other classpaths.